# Google Chrome Packaged App Pop-up?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a packaged app in Google Chrome to allow for serial communications. I need to make a pop-up help page to explain how to use it etc. I have tried several different ways that I can think of and have not found any information on here or Google itself on how to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to open a window with `chrome.app.window.create` and populate it with the help-file HTML. However, this won't allow navigation within that same window with an <a> tag. (It will navigate to an external browser window.) To get full-blown navigation, you can place a <webview> in the window, and put the help file there. The tag looks like this:

```
<webview id="webview" src="http://example.com/help" style="width:600px; height:500px"></webview>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Didn't need the webview tags as it is packaged with the app. Thanks! For Anyone needing the syntax: chrome.app.window.create(string url, CreateWindowOptions options, function callback)